# Wildcard search in o365 list

Tags: search, office365, wildcard

I have a custom list in O365 with around 3k items and I need to enable wildcard search for a column 'CourseName' in the list. I tried using SharePoint designer with filter query and filter webpart. But the issue here is "contains" Filter parameter is appearing only for the Title field. Since 'CourseName' is not a title field, I have to check for other options.

I have also tried creating Managed properties and mapping the crawled property of 'CourseName' to that Managed Property. However I cannot find the managed property. Should i reindex the site for this , or are there any other methods to do the crawling. Also I would like to know what is the scope of search when using Managed properties. Please advise.

Right now, we are not considering custom approach.